# ffmpeg error when I make TS file

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to make video from audio/image to mp4.
I want merge/concatenate two mp4 video.

I have this to make mp4 video:

```
ffmpeg -i "background.png" -i "audio.mp3" -y -r 30 -b 2500k -acodec ac3 -ab 384k -vcodec mpeg4 "result.mp4"
```

This, it works!

To concatenate two mp4 video, I must pass by ts files.

```
ffmpeg -i "result.mp4" -codec copy -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb intermediate1.ts
```

But, I have this error:

[image]

Comment: Drop `-bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb`

Comment: If I drop this, I can't read the video... Reading imposible.

Comment: That BSF is not meant for `mpeg4` so it won't have any effect.